# Set the Excel Format

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, validation

I want to write `2-7` in excel spreadsheet. when I write it, it is automatically converted in `2/7/2012`. Please let me know how can I overcome by this silly problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with a quote:

```
'2-7
```

And it should work. Alternatively you can enter a string:

```
="2-7"
```

Comment: A completely silly solution would be to enter this instead: `=TEXT("2-7","m-d")` I recommend assylias' first suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Format your column as text before you enter data.